# How to assign themes and Quickstyles in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Where I work a department has created several theme files and quickstyle colours they want used in different circumstances.

I am wanting to create a macro that when run would save the theme automatically, and then assign a quickstyle colour group.

I have tried the macro recorder does not provide any hints as the macro is blank after attempting to record the actions, this is using either the mouse or keyboard. Searched everwhere and no solutions.

I can create the ribbon tab and buttons where we will call the macros from, I have already created macros and forms to populate documents with addresses etc.

But I cannot find any where I can set and save a theme or quick style and or colours.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea for VBA is always to look into the Object Explorer in the IDE. Just press F2 while in the VBA Editor and type in the search field "theme".
There are the methods ActiveDocument.ApplyDocumentTheme(Filename as string) and ActiveDocument.ApplyTheme(Name as string). For quick styles you'll find also methods. 
I don't have the time to test it, but I guess here you can go on.